Splitting single React/Vite project into multiple entrypoints
There are a couple of questions with this sort of wording, but not quite the same approach, so I do apologize if this is retreading ground.
I am developing a React app with Vite. Let's say it has basically three pages: Home, Edit, and View. Right now I have a project structure like:
  index.html
  src/
    app.jsx
    edit.jsx
    home.jsx
    view.jsx

So currently index.html loads app.jsx, which displays one of my React components <Home/>, <Edit/>, or <View/> depending on the query parameters, i.e., ?mode=edit, etc.
What I'd like to be able to do instead is to go to edit.html instead. And also to reduce the side of a given page's loading. Currently it builds a single index-[hash].js and index-[hash].css with everything in it every time. What I'm hoping for are smaller loads, even there is some redundancy in module duplication (like React and MUI), because I don't care about space on disk as much as load time/size.
So I thought I could do:
  index.html
  edit/
    index.html
  view/
    index.html
  src/
    edit.jsx
    home.jsx
    view.jsx

and a Vite config with:
    build: {
        ...
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                edit: './edit/index.html',
                home: './index.html',
                view: './view/index.html'
            },
        }
        ...
    }

which...sort of works. In dist/assets I get a very small edit-[hash].js, home-[hash].js, and view-[hash].js, and giant component-[hash].js and component-[hash].css (where "component" is another of my React components).
The small dist/assets/*-[hash].js files are basically my reimplemented app.jsx files, which import everything from component-[hash].js|css. So it's treating the latter like a big library, which I don't know if that gains me anything at all. Plus the naming is a little wonky.
If it's at all clear what I'm trying to do here, can anyone help straighten me out?

you are doing the "premature optimization". React is made for SPA, so making it multiple is out of question. or, you can bundle up each pages to separate js file and make a backend project to serve multiple pages with them

I think you're ask too much from React, whose goal is building single page applications.
If you don't want big bundles because the initial loading time worries you; You will have to make a React application per folder; then make sure every link points to the right URL. This will add more complexity because is more deployments, duplicate code, etc.
I highly recommend React router, I think you should check it out... https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview
React Router enables "client side routing".

When the URL is yourDomain.com/ the view would be your home.jsx component
When the URL is yourDomain.com/edit the view would be your edit.jsx component
When the URL is yourDomain.com/view the view would be your view.jsx component

And many others.

I'm wondering if you just need to work on the visualization tools to explore how to reduce bundle sizes: https://codermo.medium.com/tackling-large-bundle-sizes-in-your-react-vite-app-19eae4baa39c
I'm also using React Router like @ismael-j-varela suggests, version 7 specifically which just came out Nov 2024, in addition to React 19 and Vite 6.
Here is a resource where they work on entry points documentation. Be careful, one of the entries has multiple 'thumbs down', though the others I found helpful: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/14947
I'm wondering in your case if there is even a need for multiple entry points. A home, index and edit page would seem to belong to the same app and very easily the same entry point. After the bundle loads once, the browser-side navigation to the other pages should be quick. If there are only a few 'views', React may not even be necessary, but sounds like you have enough Components to make it helpful. Hopefully it is just a bundle thing and not a massive React re-rendering issue. You can use the React Devtools for that and record using the Profiler.
